# Is $f$ a polynomial if every preimage of a one point set is bounded?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is an entire function such that for all $a \in \mathbb{C}$ the set $f^{-1}\{a\}$ is a bounded set,is it true that $f$ is a polynomial?Any hint and idea on this question is appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. By an application of Big Picard (or various weaker theorems), the function

$$g(z) = f\left(\frac 1 z\right)$$

cannot have an essential singularity at $0$, so it has a pole or is bounded there. An entire function with a pole or a bound at $\infty$ is a polynomial.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Consider $g(z)=f(1/z)$ and apply Casorati–Weierstrass to the singularity at 0.